# Settings bundle for iPhone app

Tags: objective-c, ios, settings.bundle

Right I am developing an app that has two lots of settings Dev and Live. Is there a way to distinguish which lot of settings should be used based on whether the app is live or still in development or do I have to change the whole settings files before it goes live.

I was unsure on how to put this so if your not sure place just ask.

Comment: @Downvoter If you have deemed fit to downvote please leave comment as to why, and if you are the user doing multiple downvotes across all my questions please leave reason as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want to do is define a Preprocessor Macro based on your build configuration.  So if you have a build configuration called dev and one called live you would define a different value for dev and live.

To implement this go into your apps build settings in Xcode and search for "Preprocessor Macros". Add a macro for each build target.

For dev you could add:

```
APP_CONFIG=0
```

And for live you could add:

```
APP_CONFIG=1
```

Then in your code you are able to distinguish between dev and live build configurations by a simple if statement:

```
#if APP_CONFIG == 0
    NSLog(@"This is the dev build.");
#else
    NSLog(@"This is the live build.");
#endif
```

Comment: +1 This.  It's the best way to add debugging control to your code.  You should also use this to overload NSLog to remove wasteful logging and other such things from Production-level code.

Comment: OK so this now works it distinguishes between Dev and Live but where would I put this to actually select the correct settings bundle. would I put it in the AppDelegate.m and if so where abouts?

Comment: @Popeye: Did you get any solution for this problem? I am into similar condition where I need to select the correct Settings bundle based on DEV or PROD builds. I can distinguish between the builds but have no clue where to pass the correct Settings bundle.

Comment: @Abhinav unfortunately no, sorry. I decided the best course of actual would be to change it from a settings.bundle to in app settings which allows me to set what ever I want for DEV, QA and PROD. Sorry I couldn't be any more help.