# Build-time variables with XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, jenkins-plugins

I have the following scenario:

1. A Jenkins server which builds my iOS XCode project
2. The application sources data from a URL that needs to point to a different location depending on whether the build is for production or development

I need to be able to specify, at build-time, which environment I want to build the application for such that the URL used in the code (re: `#define DATA_URL @"http://..."`) is proper for the environment being built for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do something simpler and to do this we set a macro in the build-settings under the header `Preprocessor Macros` then for each type of build (DEBUG, RELEASE, etc) set something like (DEBUG) `APP_CONFIG=1` and for (RELEASE) `APP_CONFIG=2` and so on for any others you have. Then in your `***-Prefix.pch` you can do something like (Note this doesn't have to go in `***-Prefix.pch` it can go anywhere in your code)

```
#if(APP_CONFIG==1)
    #define DATA_URL @"http://..."
#else
    #define DATA_URL @"http://..."
#endif
```

I asked something simpler a while a go here is the link [Settings bundle for iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743914/settings-bundle-for-iphone-app)

Hope this helps if it is not what you were looking for comment and I will try to amend best to help.

Comment: I think this might be exactly what I was looking for!  I'll try it out .

Comment: it did the trick!  Thanks.  I just had to duplicate my Jenkins job, and set the `Configuration` option in my build's XCode settings to `Release`