# Xcode using schemes to determine dev/staging/production server URLs

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I wish to use Xcode's schemes to determine what server to run my app against. I have an app that fetches its information from a server. Like most people I have a development server, a staging server and a production server.

I wish to create a scheme for each of these where Xcode will inject the correct URL. Do I duplicate the run scheme and add environmental variables? Is this the best way to do things, I don't particularly wish to have #ifdef's in my server class and setting it in code each time I change server. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

FYI: I'm using Xcode 5.0.2 iOS7 SDK.

[EDIT] Everyone gave some great suggestions but I feel @redent84 answer best suits my needs. Though I found it interesting that none actually suggested using different schemes. [/EDIT]

Comment: I asked something simpler sometime ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743914/settings-bundle-for-iphone-app

Comment: The best answer for this is over at Popeye's question, actually: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8744601/590767

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recommend you to create different [XCode Targets](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html) for each environment. I recommend you to change the App Identifier of the Apps, for example, the production app would be `com.mycompany.App` and the DEVEL version would be `com.mycompany.App-DEVEL`. This way you can track the Apps separately in HockeyApp or TestFlight, and you can have both applications in the same device at the same time.

Then, add Preprocessor Macros that define the environment for every target. `DEVEL` for development, for example.

If the URL is hardcoded, simply add a `#ifdef` instruction to choose the URL:

```
#ifdef DEVEL
#define ENDPOINT_URL @"http://develserver:8080/EndPoint"
#elif defined(STAGING)
#define ENDPOINT_URL @"http://stagingserver:8080/EndPoint"
#else
#define ENDPOINT_URL @"http://app.mycompany.com/EndPoint"
#endif
```

This way is less error-prone to distribute a development version, easier to maintain and allows you to add custom code to different versions. For example, you may want to include the version number in the login screen or show alert dialogs for development, but not for distribution version.

Comment: I disagree with this answer: I think targets should be thought of as **groupings of source files** so that you can produce different 'editions' of what otherwise is the same application. It should not be used for configuration because that's precisely what Xcode configurations are made for. They are much more lightweight and lets you define Preprocessor Macros exactly as in @redent84's answer as well.

Comment: @fatuhoku using XCode configurations you can't have different bundle IDs, so you can't have the different versions installed at the same time and you can't have different icons, application names or resources, which is very convenient. Not to say that is much less error prone as it's impossible to distribute a pre-production version to the AppStore by error.

Comment: @redent84 yes you TOTALLY can! The trick is to use a User-defined Setting and use it as a suffix onto the end of your bundle ID. Sorry — I should have led with this link to justify my comment. http://blog.chrismiles.info/2011/04/ios-dev-beta-production-builds.html

Comment: @fatuhoku You should probably make your answer an actual answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 5):

Use a key in the plist (for each schema, eg: URL_TO_USE), use define to create a 'shortcut' to get the value.

```
  #define MyURL [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"URL_TO_USE"]
```

**EDIT**

You must have multiple targets. Each target should point to a different .plist file. See:
[How to configure independent sets of runtime settings in XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10497552/how-to-configure-independent-sets-of-runtime-settings-in-xcode)

Comment: thanks for the reply rufo but I'm not fully understanding you. Are you suggesting separate plist files for each schema? My understanding of your suggestion is that I would create three separate keys in the plist (one for each server)?

Comment: @bennythemink: see the modification to the answer. BTW: it is 3 different plist files, not 3 different keys (the same key in each file).

Answer (score 0):

I handle this by setting custom pre-processor defines for each scheme.