# Swift: different builds connect to different servers

Tags: ios, swift, build, ipa

I have a Swift iOS project that connects to a server using HTTP. There are two servers, one for development and one for production. When I edit and test my app in Xcode, I want it to connect to the development server. Then when the code is ready, I use the following commands to build the IPA for release:

```
xcodebuild archive -scheme MyApp -archivePath ~/Archive/MyApp
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath ~/Archive/MyApp.xcarchive -exportPath ~/IPA/MyApp -exportFormat ipa -exportProvisioningProfile "My Provisioning Profile"
```

and I want this release IPA to connect to the production server. So what's the best way to do this?

Comment: A simple way is in this old answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20863628/xcode-using-schemes-to-determine-dev-staging-production-server-urls

Comment: @ciccioska: You mean creating two targets? That could work, but for my purpose it seems a little too heavy, because each time I build my app I really need only one target. Plus, maintaining two targets could be troublesome. Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Step 1: creating a Swift Compiler Custom Flag

1. In Xcode open the *Project Navigator* <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>
2. Select the *project root*
3. Select your *target*
4. Look for the `Swift Compiler - Custom Flags > Other Swift Flags` section
5. Add to `Debug` this entry: -D DEBUG

[image]

### Step 2: create a Swift Preprocessor Macro

Then write this in your code

```
#if DEBUG
let server = "http://www.yourserver.com/debug/"
#else
let server = "http://www.yourserver.com/production/"
#endif
```

Comment: I finally got the chance to try your solution. It works, and it's elegant. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create separate targets then best way is to add BASE_URL entry in a plist or a macro defined in web services handler class and then use it in all your http requests. The down side is that you will have to manually change it every time before creating IPA.

OR

Define macros like this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    NSString* const kURL = @"http://debug.com";
#else
    NSString* const kURL = @"http://release.com";
#endif
```